# What is the difference between 'var contacts = [details]()' and 'var contacts:[details]?' in ios swift

Tags: ios, swift

I wrote my code using `var contacts:[details]? = nil` and I was facing problems like I could not access `contacts?.count` and I had to use optionals everywhere. 
For e.g `contacts[indexPath.row]?.firstname`

But when I use `var contacts = [details]()` I do not have to use to optionals anywhere. I can directly use `contacts.count` and `contacts[indexPath.row].firstname`

What difference is there between the above two that we don't need to use `?` anymore even when the array is empty

Moreover using `var contacts:[details]?` was not working for me.

Comment: The code in the title does not match the code in your question. Taking your question - the difference is that one is optional and one is not. Var contacts:details? Should work - what problems were you having.

Comment: A tip to make things clearer: conventionally types (like 'details' in your code) start with a Capital letter.

Comment: Sorry  I made a mistake it is var contacts:[details]? Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: @SagerGulabani OK, no problem. You seem to misunderstand optionals a bit (I have been there too!) - if you put ? In your declaration then that Type becomes an optional, the use of ? or ! or other unwrapping methods then becomes necessary when you use it. If you don't need your array to be optional then don't use a ?. Some searches and manual reading on Optionals should help - they are useful but can get messy if used where not needed.

Answer (score 2):

First one initialises an array(of type details) and gives you an empty array while the second one just declares a variable (optional) which can be of details type

**Optionals**

`var contacts : details?`

is an optional variable (which can be of type details when not 'nil')

So whenever you are trying to access an optional variable, Swift is using optional chaining and you have to put `?`

**EDIT**

> I am not understanding where do we put ? and where do we not put it

From [Swift's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

> You specify optional chaining by placing a question mark (?) after the optional value on which you wish to call a property, method or subscript if the optional is non-nil. This is very similar to placing an exclamation mark (!) after an optional value to force the unwrapping of its value. The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is nil, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is nil.

So you put `?` when you want to unwrap the variable and call a property on it.

Comment: But somethings such as contacts?.count are not working? I am not understanding where do we put ? and where do we not put it

Comment: Yes I wrote contacts?.count I think that here ? Will come in place of !